# jqueryui.sortable and backbone collection

Tags: json, jquery-ui, backbone.js

Playing with one json api, it returns collection of models but in different order any time i accessing it (like live chart).

Wanna refresh my collection view items on models change sort order, don't re-render whole view, only swap items, with animations or smth?..

Any ideas, plugins, links.

Answer (score 1):

What about when you click for a sort, you add a listener for that, and use [Backbone's comparator function](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator)?